# Need to change data.table columns' value from "Yes" ,"No" to 1,0

Tags: r, data.table

I have a datatable object of around 0.8 million rows. Some columns in them have `Yes`/`No` values. I want to change it to `1`/`0` respectively. Here `workable_data` is my data.table object:

My code for changing (which seems too simplistic):

```
yes_No_to_1 <- function(x){
  sapply(x,function(x){
    if(x =='Yes'){
      1
      }else{
        0}
    })
} 

sapply(workable_data[,product,with=FALSE],yes_No_to_1)
```

However there are two problem s: (1) it's taking a long time and (2) I want to change the values permanently in `workable_data` in a *data.table* way.

You can reproduce sample data with:

```
product <- c("HasProduct1","HasProduct2","HasProduct3","HasProduct4","HasProduct5","HasProduct6","HasProduct7","HasProduct8","HasProduct9","HasProduct10")
workable_data <- as.data.table(data.frame(x=sample(1:100),sapply(product,function(x){x <-sample(c("Yes","No"),10000,replace = T)})))
```

I assume there is a better way to achieve this but I cant seem to figure it out and I would also appreciate any advise on optimization of my function (that is going to be the last resort). The time taken in this sample data is, which is pretty bad for 10k rows.

```
  user    system elapsed 
   6.21    0.00    6.25
```

Comment: use `factor()` to turn the collumn into factors, then `as.numeric()` to get the numbers `(workable_data[,product,with=F]$HasProduct1 %>% factor() %>% as.numeric) - 1`

Comment: `my_cols = grep("^HasProduct", names(DT), value=TRUE); DT[, (my_cols) := lapply(.SD, function(x) +(x=="Yes")), .SDcols=my_cols]` is one way. I'd recommend starting with the tutorial material for the package to understand what it's useful for and its usual syntax: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Getting-started

Comment: I have just started with data.table . I am going through the examples and can do basic stuff but the stuff u did is way ahead of my understanding as off now .Thanks .Let me test and understand

Comment: @Frank I did not quite understand the use of '+' in the anonymous function .would you pls shed some light

Comment: Sure. `x=="Yes"` is a logical (TRUE/FALSE) and `+` works the same as `as.integer` here, converting TRUE to 1L and FALSE to 0L (the L distinguishes an integer from a float in R). So it's doing the same as `ifelse(x=="Yes", 1L, 0L)` but more efficiently. I'd consider just sticking with the logical, though.

Comment: and I thought I knew basics of  R :( ,time to spend some more time

Comment: Heh, nah, `+` is just a hack that we've been using recently on SO, since folks are usually asking for their dummies to be encoded as 1/0 instead of TRUE/FALSE. It's like "code golf" (the fewer strokes/characters, the better)

Comment: btw it takes less than a second with this approach .I love this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do this with the `set` functionality in *data.table*:

**1:** Create a vector of columnnames in which you want to change the `Yes` to `1` and the `No` to `0` (like @Frank said in the comments)

```
cols <- grep("^HasProduct", names(DT), value = TRUE)
```

**2:** Change the values with the following `for(...) set(...)` implementation (as rightfully pointed out by @Arun in the comments, you can also use `as.integer` instead of just `+`):

```
for (col in cols) set(DT, j = col, value = +(DT[[col]] == "Yes"))
```

this results in:

> ```
> > DT
>         x HasProduct1 HasProduct2 HasProduct3 HasProduct4 HasProduct5 HasProduct6 HasProduct7 HasProduct8 HasProduct9 HasProduct10
>     1: 23           0           1           0           1           0           0           1           0           0            0
>     2: 74           1           0           1           1           0           1           1           1           1            1
>     3: 35           1           1           0           0           0           1           1           1           0            1
>     4:  7           1           1           1           1           0           1           1           0           0            1
>     5: 92           0           1           1           1           1           1           0           1           1            0
>    ---                                                                                                                            
>  9996: 56           0           0           1           0           1           0           0           0           1            0
>  9997: 59           1           0           1           1           0           1           1           1           1            0
>  9998: 85           0           1           0           1           1           1           1           1           1            1
>  9999: 93           1           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           1            1
> 10000: 29           0           1           1           0           0           1           0           1           1            1
> ```

Timings:

```
   user  system elapsed 
  0.007   0.000   0.007
```

---

Used data:

```
set.seed(654)
product <- c("HasProduct1","HasProduct2","HasProduct3","HasProduct4","HasProduct5","HasProduct6","HasProduct7","HasProduct8","HasProduct9","HasProduct10")
DT <- as.data.table(data.frame(x=sample(1:100),sapply(product,function(x){x <-sample(c("Yes","No"),10000,replace = T)})))
```

Comment: Nice. I'd use `as.integer()` instead of the cryptic `+`.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work, though I haven't tested it:

```
data[, zero_one := ifelse(test = (data[, yes_no] == "yes"), yes = 1, no = 0)]
```

`zero_one` is a new variable assigned using `:=` and the computation on the right is applied to each value in the data table.

Comment: And how do they do that for all 10 columns?

Comment: I believe `data[,lapply(.SD, function(x) x=='yes')]`

Answer (score 0):

In R, factors are internally treated as 1,2,3... integers corresponding to each level within a factor. "No" comes in front of "Yes" in alphabetic order, so "No" == 1L, "Yes" == 2L ("L" is just setting a number as an integer). We can retain integers from a factor and subtract 1L to arrive to "No" == 0L, "Yes" == 1L.

The advantage of this approach as compared to one of Jaap above is that factors with arbitrary level numbers can be transformed in the same way. The computational times are largely equivalent, especially for larger tables.

```
require(data.table)

# generate example data
set.seed(2020)
product <- c("HasProduct1","HasProduct2","HasProduct3","HasProduct4","HasProduct5","HasProduct6","HasProduct7","HasProduct8","HasProduct9","HasProduct10")
DT <- as.data.table(data.frame(x=sample(1:100),sapply(product,function(x){x <-sample(c("Yes","No"),10000,replace = T)})))

# define the columns to process
cols <- grep("^HasProduct", names(DT), value=TRUE)

# this is another data.table way to do it
DT[, (cols) := lapply(.SD, function(x) return(as.integer(as.factor(x)) - 1L)), .SDcols = cols]
```